# WF 4 service on IIS 7 with Platform Update 1 throwing an exception when targetFramework is set to 4.0.1

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I installed a workflow service in IIS 7 on a windows server 2008 R2 version with the new Platform Update 1 and I get this error below in the event log.

I found someone had a similar problem [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/663837/net-4-platform-update-1-cant-deploy-wcf-service-iis-with-installed-platform-update-on-server#details).  But, I was forced to change this: targetFramework="4.0.0" and then everything seems to be working.

But the question is now: is this set up correctly, now or should I have done something else?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
There was an error during processing of the managed application service auto-start for configuration path: 
'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/SiteName/Service'. The error message returned is: 'An initialization error occurred while trying to preload an application.

Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException

Message: The 'targetFramework' attribute in the <compilation> element of the Web.config file is used only to target version 4.0 and later of the .NET Framework (for example, '<compilation targetFramework="4.0">'). The 'targetFramework' attribute currently references a version that is later than the installed version of the .NET Framework. Specify a valid target version of the .NET Framework, or install the required version of the .NET Framework. (C:\MySite\MyService\web.config line 68)

StackTrace:    at System.Web.Compilation.MultiTargetingUtil.ValidateTargetFrameworkMoniker(String targetFrameworkMoniker)
   at System.Web.Compilation.MultiTargetingUtil.InitializeTargetFrameworkName()
   at System.Web.Compilation.MultiTargetingUtil.EnsureFrameworkNamesInitialized()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InitializeBuildManager()
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)'.  The worker process will be marked unhealthy and be shutdown.  The data field contains the error code.
```

Comment: This issue may be resolved by 4.0.3.  [You can check out the KB article here.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2599651)  @ me and let me know if this fixes your issue, I may try to get a canonical question/answer for this error and close dupes.  Thanks.